# Limit n->Infinity of recursive sequence

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, recursion, difference-equations

I have defined a recursive sequence

```
a[0] := 1
a[n_] := Sqrt[3] + 1/2 a[n - 1]
```

because I want to calculate the `Limit` for this sequence when n tends towards infinity.

Unfortunately I get a `recursion exceeded` error when doing:

```
Limit[a[n], n -> Infinity]
```

How can I calculate the `Limit` for this sequence using Mathematica?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alternatively, and perhaps more directly, use

```
RSolve[{a[n] == Sqrt[3] + 1/2 a[n - 1], a[0] == 1}, a[n], n]
(* {{a[n] -> 2^-n (1 - 2 Sqrt[3] + 2^(1 + n) Sqrt[3])}} *)
Limit[a[n] /. %[[1]], n -> Infinity]
(* 2 Sqrt[3] *)
```

Answer (score 6):

[Possibly this is too cheap and should just be a comment, I'm not sure.]

One way to go about such problems is to realize that "in the limit", `a[n]==a[n-1]`. So just solve an algebraic equation. If there are multiple solutions then you need to figure out which is correct based on initial values and some other reasoning.

```
Solve[x == Sqrt[3] + x/2, x]

(* Out[130]= {{x -> 2 Sqrt[3]}} *)
```

Comment: Before setting up the algebraic equation $x=\sqrt{3}+\frac x 2$, we should show that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is convergent. Namely, showing the **monotonity** and **bounded property**.

Comment: @ShutaoTang Correct. What I showed is on the quick-and-dirty side. For limiting behavior of Fibonacci sequences it does not work "out of the box", for example (you can get convergence by working with ratios of successive elements; again, showing that is a separate issue).

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: there is even more behind the "quick and dirty" method in this case. We have a linear recursion. The solution must be a sum of a Special solution of the inhomogeneous equation and the General solution of the homogeneous equation. Now the first one can be found by letting a[n] = p  which gives p = 2 Sqrt[3], the second one is A 2^-n which vanishes in the Limit so that we recover the known result.

Answer (score 5):

You can attempt to convert your sequence in terms of a function which is not recursive, then take the `Limit` of that function

```
a[0] = 1;
a[n_] := a[n] = Sqrt[3] + 1/2 a[n - 1]

seq30 = Table[a[ic], {ic, 0, 30}];
func = FindSequenceFunction[seq30, n]

Limit[func, n -> Infinity]
```

> ```
> 2^(1 - n) (1 - 2 Sqrt[3] + 2^n Sqrt[3])
>
> 2 Sqrt[3]
> ```

Answer (score 3):

As of version 11.2, this can be dealt with by `RSolveValue[]`:

```
RSolveValue[{a[n] == Sqrt[3] + 1/2 a[n - 1], a[0] == 1}, a[∞], n]
   2 Sqrt[3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use `SequenceLimit`:

```
SequenceLimit[a /@ Range[10]]
```

> 2 Sqrt[3]