# Finding the limit of a recursive sequence

Tags: recursion

I have come across a few different questions relating to my issue (namely [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103675/limit-n-infinity-of-recursive-sequence) one, but the answers are not working for me. Here are my inputs;

```
{Slider[Dynamic[c], {0, 2}], Dynamic[c]}
Dynamic[RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == (c + a[n]^2)/2, a[1] == c/2},a, {n, 1, 20}]]
Dynamic[ListPlot[RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == (c + a[n]^2)/2, a[1] == c/2},a, {n, 1, 20}]]]
```

These work so far and are just to help me visualize the sequence and its values. Then I try

```
Dynamic[RSolveValue[{a[n + 1] == (c + a[n]^2)/2, a[1] == c/2}, a[Infinity], n]]
(* RSolveValue[{a[1+n]==1/2 (0.715 +a[n]^2),a[1]==0.3575},a[\[Infinity]],n] *)
```

And I can't seem to get it to output the limit (when one exists, namely when c is less than or equal to 1). I've tried a couple of the different solutions from that thread  but I can't get it to work. Most of the time it just reprints my input like the above. I'm trying to avoid defining my function because then I have to shift the index (n+1 to n), which I don't want to make a habit of.

I'm new to Mathematica so my apologies for any mistakes. Is there a way to get this thing to give me the limit or let me know if it doesn't exist?

Comment: As with tghe prior post, you can get a finite list of candidates by solving a quadratic (in this case) like so. `In[919]:= Solve[ainf == (c + ainf^2)/2, ainf]

Out[919]= {{ainf -> 1 - Sqrt[1 - c]}, {ainf -> 1 + Sqrt[1 - c]}}`. It is not difficult to reason by induction that the first is the correct limit: `c<=1` by assumption, so `a[1]<=1/2` and for all `n`, `a[n+1]<=1/2+a[n]^2/2<1/2+1/2`.

Comment: I should add that my reasoning about convergence only applies for `-1<=c<=1`. For values where `c<-1` some experimenting indicates we have limit cycles.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that Infinity is not a number. But you may choose a large number and calculate a[n] for e.g. 1000 and 10000 and check if they are the same.

E.g. you may write:

```
Dynamic[RSolveValue[{a[n + 1] == (c + a[n]^2)/2, a[1] == cc/2},  a[1000], n]]
Dynamic[RSolveValue[{a[n + 1] == (c + a[n]^2)/2, a[1] == cc/2}, a[10000], n]]
```

Then you get:

[image]

Comment: I see! I'm guessing then that RSolveValue can only take in finite values? To that end, may I ask; would there be a way to use Limit[] and have n -> Infinity? Choosing a large number manually might leave some room for human (my) error. Additionally, it'd be more comforting to have the function tell me explicitly "There is a limit; this" or "There is no limit".

Comment: I haver no proof, but I think that "Limit" tries to get a symbolic solution and fails for this non linear recursion equation.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to look for stable points of the iteration. For example:

```
Solve[astar == (c + astar^2)/2, astar]

{{astar -> 1 - Sqrt[1 - c]}, {astar -> 1 + Sqrt[1 - c]}}
```

So these two values 1+/-Sqrt[c] are the only candidates for stable points. If you linearize, you find

```
D[(c + astar^2)/2, astar]
astar
```

So only the first of the these (with the minus sign) is a stable equilibrium (assuming 1>c>0).

Answer (score 3):

The OP question is more appropriate for [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com) but the limit seems to be `1 - Sqrt[1 - c]` for `-3<=c<=1`.

`a1` can be `0` instead of `c/2` since it only shifts the sequence by one position.

$$\left\{-3\leq c\leq 1,a_1=0,a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n^2+c}{2},\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}a_n=1-\sqrt{1-c}\right\}$$